# Make a balance table in R that can be exported to HTML

Tags: r

I'm trying to make a balance table like this in R:
[image]

I want to be able to output it to HTML and re-label the columns, and to have an option to show p-values of the comparison of means between the two groups.

The package `crosstable` almost works, but I could not find a way to treat the categorical variables as continuous. Here's the code:

```r
library(crosstable)

# Make list of clean labels for columns 
mtcars_labels = read.table(header=TRUE, text="
  name  label
  model 'Model'
  mpg   'Miles/(US) gallon'
  cyl   'Number of cylinders'
  disp  'Displacement (cu.in.)'
  hp    'Gross horsepower'
  drat  'Rear axle ratio'
  wt    'Weight (1000 lbs)'
  qsec  '1/4 mile time'
  vs    'Engine'
  am    'Transmission'
  gear  'Number of forward gears'
  carb  'Number of carburetors'
")

# Apply column labels to mtcars 
mydata = mtcars  %>%  import_labels(mtcars_labels, name_from="name", label_from="label")

crosstable(mydata,by=vs, test=TRUE, funs=c(mean=mean, "std error"=sd)) %>% 
  as_flextable()
```

And an extract of the table it makes:
[image]

`CreateTableOne` is also almost perfect, but I don't see a way to make .tex or HTML output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean something like this:

```
library(crosstable)
library(flextable)

ft1 <- crosstable(mydata,by="Engine", test=TRUE, funs=c(mean=mean, "std error"=sd)) %>% 
  as_flextable()


tf1 <- tempfile(fileext = ".html")
save_as_html(ft1, path = tf1)
browseURL(tf1)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I'm reverting this question to unanswered because I realized that with crosstable, the categorical variables are not shown in my desired way. For example: I'd like to see P(Transmission=1| Engine=0), but it's showing P(Engine=0 | Transmission=1). Haven't been able to change that so I might need to use a different table command

Comment: This is o.k. But what you could also do is to open a new question and refer to this one. It is up to you.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the answer of TarJae, I declared all variables to be non-categorical (see [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/crosstable/vignettes/crosstable.html#categorical-variables)) with `unique_numeric = 1` and then replaced the variable(s) that should be listed as categorical variable as factor variable.

```r
library(crosstable)
library(flextable)

data = mtcars
data$vs = factor(data$vs)

# Make list of clean labels for columns 
mtcars_labels = read.table(header=TRUE, text="
  name  label
  model 'Model'
  mpg   'Miles/(US) gallon'
  cyl   'Number of cylinders'
  disp  'Displacement (cu.in.)'
  hp    'Gross horsepower'
  drat  'Rear axle ratio'
  wt    'Weight (1000 lbs)'
  qsec  '1/4 mile time'
  vs    'Engine'
  am    'Transmission'
  gear  'Number of forward gears'
  carb  'Number of carburetors'
")

# Apply column labels to modified mtcars 
mydata = data %>%  import_labels(mtcars_labels, name_from="name", label_from="label")

my_table <- crosstable(mydata,by="Engine", test=TRUE, unique_numeric = 1,
    funs=c(mean=mean, "std error"=sd)) %>% as_flextable()
print(my_table)
```

The last line prints the table, giving you the option to save the output. (In R-Studio Viewer -> Export -> Save as Webpage..., in R itself opens a temporary .html in the browser that can be saved)

Comment: This is really useful! But I was still hoping to keep the functionality where categorical variables are treated differently (shown as counts (%)). See my answer above.

Answer (score 0):

I implemented a solution that takes the `TableOne` object, makes it into a dataframe, and uses `kableExtra` and `kableExtra` to make the dataframe into an HTML table. Using the mtcars dataset, the output is:
[image]

Code:

```r
library(tableone)
library(kableExtra)

############# EDIT THESE  ###############################################################
# The name of your dataframe 
df_name = "mtcars" 

# The names of the two groups (e.g. treatment, control)
group1_name = "V engine"
group2_name = "Straight engine"

# The variables you want to show
varlist = c("am","carb","disp","cyl","mpg","gear","vs")

# The categorical variables from that list
factors = c(                   "cyl",      "gear","vs")

# The variable you want to split on
split_by = "vs"

# Pretty name labels. Same order as varlist 
pretty_names = c("Manual","Number of carburetors","Displacement","Cylinders","MPG","Forward Gears","VS")

# A note you want to add at the bottom
my_note = "This table shows descriptive statistics for the two primary groups in the analysis. For continuous variables, we show means with standard deviations in parentheses. For categorical variables, we give the frequency of that value with the percent in parentheses."
#########################################################################

# Create TableOne object 
bt = CreateTableOne(vars = varlist, 
                    factorVars = factors, strata = split_by, 
                    data = get(df_name)) 


# Now loop through to edit rownames 
new_rownames <- c("N")
rows_to_indent = c()

# Loop over each variable in varlist 
for (item in varlist) {
  pretty_name = pretty_names[which(varlist==item)]
  # For categorical variables, add extra rows (one for each value)
  if (item %in% factors) {
    # Only shows multiple rows if there are 3 cats or more 
    if (length(names(table(get(df_name)[item])))>2) {
      new_rownames <- c(new_rownames, paste0(pretty_name," (%)"), names(table(get(df_name)[item])))
      index = which(new_rownames==paste0(pretty_name," (%)"))
      rows_to_indent = c(rows_to_indent,seq(index+1,index+length(names(table(get(df_name)[item])))))
    } else {
      new_rownames <- c(new_rownames, paste0(pretty_name," (%)"))
    }
    
  } else {
    new_rownames <- c(new_rownames, pretty_name)
  }
}

# Print the TableOne output and make into dataframe
df = as.data.frame(print(bt, quote=FALSE, noSpaces = TRUE)) 
names(df) = c(group1_name,group2_name,"P-value of difference","")
df2 = as.matrix(df)

# Give correct rownames
rownames(df2) = new_rownames

# Delete last column (not used)
df2 = df2[,-4]

# Output kable table depending on whether categorical values need indenting
if (length(rows_to_indent) > 0) {
  kable(df2, format = "html") %>% 
    kable_styling() %>%
    add_footnote(my_note) %>%
    add_indent(rows_to_indent)
} else {
  kable(df2, format = "html") %>% 
    kable_styling() %>%
    add_footnote(my_note) 
}
```