# Make a simple balance table in R (with HTML output)

Tags: r

I'm trying to make a balance table like this in R (Can think of the first two columns as "treatment" and "control") that can be output to HTML. Each entry is the average of that variable within the group indicated by the column. The last column is the p-value of the difference between the two averages.
[image: balance table example]

(This is why my question is so similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76122809/make-a-balance-table-in-r-that-can-be-exported-to-html) but not the same!)

`CreateTableOne` is also almost perfect, but I don't see a way to make .tex or HTML output.

With `crosstable`, the categorical variables are not shown in my desired way. For example: I'd like to see P(DUMMY_VAR=1| TREATMENT=0), but it shows P(TREATMENT=0 | DUMMY_VAR=1). Haven't been able to change that so I might need to use a different table command.

Comment: Look at packages `gt`, `kableExtra`, `stargazer`, perhaps `xtable`, and likely other packages that help do report-worthy tables like this.

Comment: @braces I posted an answer on your other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76122809/make-a-balance-table-in-r-that-can-be-exported-to-html) that might resolve this question as well.